# Open questions in Topological K-Theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics, topological-k-theory, string-theory

I am interested in knowing about current research in the Topological K-Theory, especially its interactions with String Theory. About one and a half decade back, there were some papers by Physicists (e.g. [1](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0007175), [2](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9810188)) about relation of Topological K-theory to string theory. Are there any interesting open problems in this area ?

> What are the current open problems in Topological K- Theory motivated by String Theory ?

My immediate interest is in Topological K-Theory (and not much in [differential K-theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.6663) or K-theory of operator algebras or Algebraic K-theory).

Please advise some recent review paper in this area.

Comment: You want to take a look at Dan Freed's page: https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/